# UIImagePickerController crash on opening camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to open the camera like this:

```
mediaPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[mediaPicker setDelegate:self];
mediaPicker.allowsEditing = YES;

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
       mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
       [self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But I'm getting a crash saying:

```
-[UIImage setClipsToBounds:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1245aa9a0
```

> Stacktrace:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1812bae38 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18091ff80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1812c1ccc -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 212
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1812bec74 ___forwarding___ + 872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1811bcd1c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   CameraKit                       0x18a3ce460 -[CMKBlurredSnapshotView initWithView:] + 344
6   CameraKit                       0x18a40cb3c -[CMKCameraView _setupSuspensionSnapshotViewWithBlur:] + 88
7   CameraKit                       0x18a3fd0d0 -[CMKCameraView enableCamera] + 296
8   CameraKit                       0x18a3f549c -[CMKCameraView viewWillBeDisplayed] + 184
9   PhotoLibrary                    0x18c11c7d4 -[PLImagePickerCameraView viewWillBeDisplayed] + 220
10  PhotoLibrary                    0x18c0ec42c -[PLUICameraViewController viewWillAppear:] + 576
11  UIKit                           0x18641d274 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 628
12  UIKit                           0x18641cfe8 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 156
13  UIKit                           0x1864c44a0 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 760
14  UIKit                           0x1864c3ddc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 868
15  UIKit                           0x18679e904 -[UINavigationController _setViewControllers_7_0:transition:animated:operation:] + 3052
16  UIKit                           0x18679da00 -[UINavigationController _setViewControllers:transition:animated:operation:] + 620
17  UIKit                           0x18679cbfc __54-[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:]_block_invoke + 1232
18  UIKit                           0x1867835e4 +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitions:] + 128
19  UIKit                           0x186543e50 -[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:] + 412
20  UIKit                           0x186683bd0 -[UIImagePickerController _setupControllersForCurrentSourceType] + 172
21  UIKit                           0x186683a84 -[UIImagePickerController viewWillAppear:] + 84
22  UIKit                           0x18641d274 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 628
23  UIKit                           0x18641cfe8 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 156
24  UIKit                           0x18676424c __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 960
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: You are calling `setClipsToBounds` on a UIImage when it should be called on a UIImageView. That's whats causing the crash. Show us where are you calling `setClipsToBounds`

Comment: I'm not calling 'setClipsToBounds' anywhere.

Comment: The log says that you are calling it or doing something which calls that. As for your code to present UIImagePickerController, it is correct. The crash is not because of that but instead because of what log and I told you

Comment: I've double checked the code, and there is no call to setClipsToBounds. I'm guessing the UIImagePickerController is calling it somewhere.

Comment: set cliptobounds is the property not the method, the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Have you tried setting allowsEditing to NO?

Comment: try once `mediaPicker.allowsEditing = NO;`

Comment: I tried it, it's not working.

Comment: Can you send your `imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])`?

Comment: The delegate method is not even getting called.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik `clipsToBound` is a property. `setClipsToBound` is its setter method. And the log mentions the method aka selector.

Comment: @FábioSalata That's swift. OP is using objective C. And damjandd, add objective c tag to your post to attract right audience

Comment: Where are you calling this method ?Pls show the complete stack trace of the crash.@damjandd

Comment: Are you using any library for opening the camera ?@damjandd

Comment: I think @NSNoob is right, the problem is that setClipsToBounds is not being found, which means that there is a UIImage where there should be a UIImageView.

Comment: Here is the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/VAEKnVPr

Comment: as you are using a library, pls post the method initWithView:] in  [CMKBlurredSnapshotView class! There  must be something crzy going on in that class!@damjandd

Comment: I'm not using any library, the code that you see is all that I have.

Comment: @damjandd stacktrace clearly shows that you are using CameraKit. Look for the class CMKBlurredSnapshotView in your project. Also try enabling exception breakpoint and see where it hits when the crash happened.

Comment: You may not use the library, but PLImagePickerCameraView is using it! @damjandd

Comment: There is nothing we can do about this issue, as this looks like a bug in the CameraKit framework.@damjandd

Comment: I already have the exception breakpoint enabled, but it doesn't catch the issue. The camera CMKBlurredSnapshotView cannot be found in the project as its part of a framework.

Answer (score 1):

I've got exactly the same issue, It is caused by a swift extension which named "snapshotView() -> UIImage" extended UIView in my code.

As the "CMKBlurredSnapshotView" in CameraKit has a same method named "snapshotView" but returning a UIView, so my code overrode the system original method but return a UIImage, So the exception is thrown.

You should check all your code and verify if you make the same mistake.